# WindowProc For a form in c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I how to get the windowproc for a form in c# for .net compact framework 3.5,

i want to know how to get the window proc of particular form.

By default we cant overide the window proc of a form in c# 3.5 compact, please let alternate

method to get the windowproc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for my question

[My Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465864/can-anyone-tell-me-were-i-am-making-mistake-in-the-snippet/1465941#1465941)

Answer (score 3):

All the info you need and examples are available in MSDN:

- [How to: Use a Class for Hooking Windows Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229658.aspx)
- [Subclassing Controls with a Managed Window Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229681.aspx)
- etc ([Interoperability in the .NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3f1t3ct.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to hook into the windows messages, you could always use the [OpenNETCF SDF](http://www.opennetcf.com/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=ZZBxc7fhnz4%3d&tabid=65&mid=959) library which has an ApplicationEx class. This class allows you to filter messages at the application level.

Alternatively, there are blog entries [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/raffael/archive/2008/02/26/subclassing-netcf-applications.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/netcfteam/archive/2005/05/23/421143.aspx) that might be of some help to you.

Comment: Hey, i agree with you..
But the sample says we need to override an even and perform sendmessage. BUt i dont want that.. i want to get message like win32 dialog application.. there we have windproc and we will register the proc.. then we perform peekmessage(),dispatchmessage() then we get all the event related to dialogue na.. same way i want to get all the even related to from.. how to achive this